# Scilab - gui - many unknown variables error messages

Tags: scilab

Still trying to understand the logic of Scilab, I created a small calculation tool for a mechanical element. The main problem I have is finding the right order (or syntax) for the calculation code... I get a lot of "unknown variable" errors and I don't understand why? 
I tried to change the order of definitions for the functions, declare the variables as global, etc. but nothing seems to help.
The code for the calculation is not long and also not complicated, but the gui was built using guibuilder, so the uicontrols definitions are probably much longer than they need to be.
Could somebody help me make this code working, as I would learn and understand a lot by this example, althought it contains more than one "problem zones"?
Here what I've done:

```
G = 78500;

table_titles = ["" "Wire diameter" "Wp" "Tau alwd" "M alwd" "Angle alwd"];

f=figure('figure_position',[910,163],'figure_size',
[903,537],'auto_resize','on','background',[33],'figure_name','Graphic 
window number %d');
//////////
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('File'))
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('?'))
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('Tools'))
toolbar(f.figure_id,'off')
handles.dummy = 0;
handles.sl_dwire=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',
[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','Tahoma',
'FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','normal',
'ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','left','ListboxTop',
[],'Max',[12],'Min',[0],'Position',
[0.0058208,0.77875,0.124375,0.06875],'Relief','default','SliderStep',
[0.1,1],'Style','slider','String',"Wire diameter",'Value',
[6],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','sl_dwire',
'Callback','sl_dwire_callback(handles)')
handles.ed_dwire=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',
[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','off','FontAngle','normal','FontName','Tahoma',
'FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','normal',
'ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','left','ListboxTop',
[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],
'Position',[0.0058208,0.71875,0.124375,0.06875],'Relief',
'default','SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String',"wire diameter: " + 
msprintf('%2.1f',handles.sl_dwire.Value) + "mm",'Style','text',
'Value',[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag',
'ed_dwire','Callback','auto')
handles.sl_wangle=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',
[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','Tahoma',
'FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','normal',
'ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','left',
'ListboxTop',[],'Max',[180],'Min',[5],'Position',
[0.0090625,0.5191667,0.25625,0.0645833],'Relief','default',
'SliderStep',[0.1,1],'String','Working angle','Style','slider','Value',
[50],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','sl_wangle',
'Callback','sl_wangle_callback(handles)')
handles.ed_wangle=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',
[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','off','FontAngle','normal','FontName','Tahoma',
'FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','normal',
'ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','left',
'ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',
[0.0090625,0.4591667,0.25625,0.0645833],'Relief','default',
'SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String',"Working angle: " + 
msprintf('%2.1f',handles.sl_wangle.Value) + "°",'Style','text',
'Value',[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag',
'ed_wangle','Callback','auto')
handles.sl_activel=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized',
'BackgroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal',
'FontName','Tahoma','FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight',
'normal','ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','left',
'ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1000],'Min',[10],'Position',
[0.0090625,0.365,0.25625,0.0645833],'Relief','default',
'SliderStep',[0.1,1],'String','Active length' ,'Style','slider',
'Value',[10],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag',
'sl_activel','Callback','sl_activel_callback(handles)')
handles.ed_activel=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized',
'BackgroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','off','FontAngle','normal',
'FontName','Tahoma','FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight',
'normal','ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','left',
'ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',
[0.0090625,0.305,0.25625,0.0645833],'Relief','default',
'SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String','Active length: ' + 
msprintf('%2.1f',handles.sl_activel.Value) +
"mm",'Style','text','Value',[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible',
'on','Tag','ed_activel','Callback','auto')
handles.ax_graph= newaxes();handles.ax_graph.margins = [ 0 0 0 0];
handles.ax_graph.axes_bounds = [0.4274266,0.0619266,0.3995485,0.5191743];
handles.tab_param=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',
[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName',
'Tahoma','FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','normal',
'ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','left',
'ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],
'Position',[0.4308126,0.1690826,0.3950339,0.2178899],'Relief',
'default','SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String',string(table_param),'Style',
'table','Value',[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible',
'on','Tag','tab_param','Callback','tab_param_callback(handles)')
handles.sl_sfactor=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized',
'BackgroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal',
'FontName','Tahoma','FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight',
'normal','ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','left',
'ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],
'Position',[0.0058208,0.6525688,0.124375,0.06875],'Relief','default',
'SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String',"Safety factor",'Style',
'slider','Value',[0.58],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on',
'Tag','ed_sfactor','Callback','sl_sfactor_callback(handles)')
handles.ed_sfactor=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized',
'BackgroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','off','FontAngle','normal',
'FontName','Tahoma','FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight',
'normal','ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment',
'left','ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',
[0.0058208,0.5925688,0.124375,0.06875],'Relief','default',
'SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String',"Safety factor : " + 
msprintf('%2.1f',handles.sl_sfactor.Value),'Style',
'text','Value',[0.58],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on',
'Tag','ed_dwire','Callback','auto')
handles.popm_wtype=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized',
'BackgroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal',
'FontName','Tahoma','FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight',
'normal','ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','left',
'ListboxTop',[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',
[0.0058208,0.8618349,0.124375,0.0639450],'Relief','default',
'SliderStep',[0.01,0.1],'String',gettext("SL/DL|SM/DM|SH/DH"),'Style',
'popupmenu','Value',[2],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on',
'Tag','popm_wtype','Callback','popm_wtype_callback(handles)')

//////////
// Callbacks are defined as below. Please do not delete the comments
as it will be used in coming version
//////////

function sl_sfactor_callback(handles)
   sf=handles.sl_sfactor.Value; 
   handles.ed_sfactor.String="Safety factor: " + msprintf('%3.2f',sf);
endfunction

function sl_dwire_callback(handles)
   wd=handles.sl_dwire.Value;
   Wp = %pi*wd^3/16;
   Ip =%pi*wd^4/32;
   Kt = G*%pi*Ip/(180*L);
   Talwd = sf * calcform;
   Malwd = Wp * Talwd;
   alphaalwd = Malwd / Kt;
   x=0:0.1:alphaalwd*1.5;
   plot(x,Kt*x);
   handles.ed_dwire.String="Wire diameter: " + 
   msprintf('%2.1f',wd) + "mm";
endfunction

function popm_wtype_callback(handles)
//Write your callback for  popm_wtype  here
     if selected == 1 then
     calcform =(1845 - 700*log10(wd));
 elseif selected == 2  then
     calcform =(2105 - 780*log10(wd));
 elseif selected == 3 then
     calcform = (2220 - 820*log10(wd));
 end
endfunction

function sl_wangle_callback(handles)
    handles.ed_wangle.String="Working angle: " + 
    msprintf('%2.1f',handles.sl_wangle.Value) + "°";   
endfunction

function sl_activel_callback(handles)
//Write your callback for  sl_activel  here
    handles.ed_activel.String="Active length: " + 
    msprintf('%2.1f',handles.sl_activel.Value) + "mm";
    L=handles.sl_activel.Value;
endfunction

function tab_param_callback(handles)
//Write your callback for  tab_param  here
   table_values = string([ wd Wp Talwd Malwd alphaalwd]);
   table_param = [table_titles; [table_values]];
endfunction
```

I expect the code to dynamically update the graph and the parameters table according to the positions of input sliders and popup-menu.

Again, it would be very helpful if somebody could help me get this code working, as I would get answers for a lot of my questions concerning programming with scilab.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It seems your problem is that you don't understand how scopes are limited in Scilab. You create variables inside functions and try to call them from outside that function. That is not allowed.

Comment: I tried understanding your code, but it's too complicated. Can you make a very simple example with guibuilder? Maybe just one slider, or one single equation? It has to be one that have the same problem of "undefined variable". That's what we call [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is not directly executable, caused by the linebreaks. Please add `...` after each line of a statement. This improves also the readability.
As mentioned by @luispauloml, you try to use variables, which exist just inside of another function. For example you try to reach `table_param`, which is just alive in `tab_param_callback(handles)`.
To get rid of this, you have to define the output for the function:

> function [table_values, table_param] = tab_param_callback(handles)
>
> table_values = string([ wd Wp Talwd Malwd alphaalwd]);
>
> table_param = [table_titles; [table_values]];
>
> endfunction

Now you can call this function to get the variable:

> string(tab_param_callback(handles))

I corrected just this case and added the dots as explained. For the other variables, it can be done analogously. Furthermore, I moved the function definition to the beginning of the code. Because if your scrips crashed in the middle, the compiler has no chance to read the function definitions.

Please find the code in [this file](https://tubcloud.tu-berlin.de/s/HGuDyaVJf1Y3M6S) .

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Btw:The syntax for statements over several line is the same as in MATLAB.https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/continue-long-statements-on-multiple-lines.html